# Equivalent of formatted printf (c) to formatted cerr in C++

Tags: c++, c, printf

I want an equivalent for `printf("%2.2x", var);` to `cerr<<` in C++.
code:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;  
static byte var[10];  
for(i=1; i<10; i++)  
   printf("%2.2x", var[i]);
```

The idea is to redirect the debugging to a file like this: `./myprog 2>out.txt`.
If I don't ask too much I would like to receive explanations too.
Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, you probably did not mean to use `static` to declare your array.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, e.g.:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%2.2x", var[i]);
```

Comment: If both `fprintf(stderr,...)` and `std::cerr` are used, will they play together nicely with the same buffer?

Comment: IIRC `stderr` and `cerr` should be un-buffered, and anyway synchronization is on by default. It should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the stream manipulators in C++, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...
std::cerr << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setprecision(2) << (int)var[i];
```

I *think* `setw` is correct here, but have a play around, and some more are listed here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/

Comment: Not the same as `printf("%2.2x", var[i]);`. You should convert `var[i]` to int before printing. Otherwise characters will be printed, not hexadecimal representation.

Comment: this method prints me some spaces that I didn't expect

Comment: That could be because of the setw. Have a play around with the options, as it's been a while since I've used this.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/):

```
std::cerr << boost::format("%2.2x") % static_cast<int>(var[i]);
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this.  All the familiarity of C-style formatters, plus some actual run-time type safety?  Neat.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void show_a_byte(unsigned char val) {
    std::ostream out(std::cerr.rdbuf());
    out << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setprecision(2)
        << static_cast<unsigned int>(val);
}
```

I used a temporary `ostream` sharing `cerr`'s buffer to make sure none of the manipulators leave undesired side effects on `cerr`.  The `static_cast` is needed because when `ostream` gets a (`signed` or `unsigned` or plain) `char`, it thinks it can just copy it as a raw byte.

Comment: Note that you also need a `#include <iomanip>` to use setw().